Is there a better approach to upgrading to Timber 2?
We got the task of updating Timber 1 to Timber 2 in a legacy theme (10 years old). There are many Twig templates and PHP files that should be changed in the theme. We do not have the capacity for such a huge change, so we started searching for other solutions.
As we have many descendant classes of Timber\Post and we instantiate them through their constructors the Timber::get_post()-like instantiation would increase the amount of the to be changed files.
Furthermore, our solution highly depends on the presence of the ACF fields on the post instance, as Timber 1 provided them earlier.
To avoid the enormous changes in the existing code, we decided to extend the Timber\Post class keeping the ability of the usage of constructors and providing the ACF fields.
The constructor fetches and attaches the ACF fields to the corresponding instance. We did the same thing in the case of Terms.
We chose this solution because we have to focus on other more important problems and now we do not have the capacity to rewrite the existing code. We need Timber 2 to be in place implement new features with it and rewrite the old code when it needs to be changed.
And the question:
What concerns can be seen in this solution?
Could other approaches and solutions be mentioned?
Our main goal here is to have Timber 2 running and keeping the number of changes as low as possible.
Below is the custom Post class that became the new ancestor of our other classes. This way we needed to change extends \Timber\Post  to extends \Custom\Theme\Timber\Post and everything started working.
namespace Custom\Theme\Timber;

use Timber\Timber;

class Post extends \Timber\Post
{
    public function __construct( $pid = null )
    {
        $ancestor = Timber::get_post( $pid );
        $customs = $this->get_post_custom( $ancestor->id );
        $this->import( array_merge( (array) $ancestor, (array) $customs, [ 'custom' => $customs ] ) );
        $this->wp_object = $ancestor->wp_object;
    }

    public static function build( \WP_Post $wp_post ): static
    {
        $post = parent::build( $wp_post );
        $customs = $post->get_post_custom( $post->id );
        $post->import( array_merge( (array) $customs, [ 'custom' => $customs ] ) );
        return $post;
    }

    protected function get_post_custom( $pid ) {
        $post_meta = get_post_meta( $pid );
        foreach ( $post_meta as $key => $value ) {
            if ( is_array( $value ) && count( $value ) == 1 && isset( $value[ 0 ] ) ) {
                $value = $value[ 0 ];
            }
            $post_meta[ $key ] = maybe_unserialize( $value );
        }
        return $post_meta;
    }
}

